# static constexpr class member variable safe for multithreading reads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Is it safe to have a static constexpr member variable of a class being read simultaneously by multiple threads? e.g.:

```
class A{
  public:
    //some code here
  private:
    static constexpr std::size_t x_ = 99;

}
```

If I create multiple objects of type Class `A`, each object being used by a different thread, it it safe for each C++11 thread to independently read the member variable `x_` without using any locking mechanisms?

Comment: Note that since `x_` is a compile time constant, there may not even be any access to `x_` at runtime.

Comment: why might there not be any access to x_ at runtime? Under what conditions? I do not seem to have a problem accessing the variable at runtime.

Comment: It's a compile time constant. It's always `99`. So the compiler can easily inline any access to `x_` and replace it with the value `99` directly. It might still be read, for example if you are dereferencing a pointer to an `std::size_t` that happens to point to `x_`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.  A data race happens when you have multiple threads and at least one of them is a writer and you have have no synchronization.  If none of your threads are a writer (and you can't, because it is `const`) then you can't have a data race.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple simultaneous reads are always thread safe, as long as there is no concurrent write going on.